# Issue with the awk command

Tags: shell, awk

I have a script which is throwing a below error any one can trace i am stuck on this for past 4 hrs

The script contains below: vi  bb.sh

```
#!/bin/awk -f
'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{$1="";++a[$0];next} {field1=$1;$1=""; if ( !(a[$0]) ) {$1=field1;print $0} }' /home/path/a.txt  /home/path/b.txt >  /home/path/c.txt
```

error after execution :

```
-bash-4.2$ sh bb.sh
bb.sh: line 2: BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{$1="";++a[$0];next} {field1=$1;$1=""; if ( !(a[$0]) ) {$1=field1} }: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `awk` in the script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{$1="";++a[$0];next} {field1=$1;$1=""; if ( !(a[$0]) ) {$1=field1;print $0} }' \
/home/path/a.txt  /home/path/b.txt >  /home/path/c.txt
```

The script should probably also have `#!/bin/sh` as its first line.

Alternatively, you'll convert the script into a proper `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"} 

NR==FNR { $1="";++a[$0]; next }

{
  field1 = $1;
  $1 = ""; 
  if ( !(a[$0]) ) {
     $1 = field1;
     print $0;
  }
}
```

... and then run it with, e.g.

```
$ ./bb.awk /home/path/a.txt /home/path/b.txt >/home/path/c.txt
```

Comment: Hi sir thank you for the answer but the path  
" /home/path/a.txt   /home/path/b.txt >/home/path/c.txt"  should be dynamically appended to the script

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku if you mean you want to specify the target files when you run it, see my answer. You have an `awk` script there, don't try to run it as a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `awk` script but are trying to run it as an `sh` script. That won't work. You have two choices:

1. Run it as an awk script instead. Since your file already has a shebang line (`#!/bin/awk -f`), just remove the quotes and the input files:

   ```
   #!/bin/awk -f
   BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{$1="";++a[$0];next} {field1=$1;$1=""; if ( !(a[$0]) ) {$1=field1;print $0} }
   ```

   Then, make it executable (`chmod a+x bb.sh`), and run it:

   ```
   ./bb.sh  /home/path/a.txt  /home/path/b.txt >  /home/path/c.txt
   ```

   You might also want to remove the `.sh` extension or rename it to `.awk` so it doesn't confuse you. The computer won't care, that's just there for you.
2. Convert it into a shell script that runs the `awk` command:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{$1="";++a[$0];next} {field1=$1;$1=""; if ( !(a[$0]) ) {$1=field1;print $0} }' /home/path/a.txt  /home/path/b.txt >  /home/path/c.txt
   ```